# python2.7 fails with ImportError: No module named time under cygwin

Tags: python, windows, cygwin

I recently installed cygwin on my Windows 8 desktop pc for network analysis / performance evaluation in my home network

after installation, I failed with easy_install:

```
$ python ez_setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ez_setup.py", line 67, in <module>
    except ImportError: from md5 import md5
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/md5.py", line 10, in <module>
    from hashlib import md5
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 141, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
ImportError: No module named time
```

my analysis so far showed that cygwin python 2.7 is unable to locate time.dll:

```
python -vvv
>>> import time
# trying time.dll
# trying timemodule.dll
# trying time.py
# trying time.pyc
# trying /usr/lib/python2.7/time.dll
# trying /usr/lib/python2.7/timemodule.dll
# trying /usr/lib/python2.7/time.py
# trying /usr/lib/python2.7/time.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named time
```

but time.dll is installed (but not in the directories searched):

```
$ find /usr/lib/python2.7/ -name "time*"
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.dll

$ ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.dll
        ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7fff41430000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7fff408c0000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7fff3e970000)
        fshook64.dll => /cygdrive/c/program files (x86)/f-secure/apps/computersecurity/hips/fshook64.dll (0x56640000)
        PSAPI.DLL => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/PSAPI.DLL (0x7fff40d40000)
        ADVAPI32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/ADVAPI32.dll (0x7fff405f0000)
        msvcrt.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/msvcrt.dll (0x7fff3ef00000)
        sechost.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/sechost.dll (0x7fff40ea0000)
        RPCRT4.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/RPCRT4.dll (0x7fff40a00000)
        libpython2.7.dll => /usr/bin/libpython2.7.dll (0x53bb50000)
        cygwin1.dll => /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll (0x180040000)
```

hope it is not related to F-Secure (where I had lately serious troubles with VirtualBox). Also, I had to set environment variables PATH, PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH as follows:

```
export PYTHONHOME=/usr/bin
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32
```

but does not help. Also adding '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/' to PATH does not help.

Answer (score 3):

finally I found the cause of the problem:

PYTHONHOME was set to /usr/bin
after fixing that and changing to /usr
it works now.